# "App isn't responding" when use NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I don't know why but when I use NestedScrollView my app starts to hang and then "App isn't responding" popup appear. I'm not even getting any error in the log. Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/srlFeed"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.CustomSpinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg"
                android:dropDownVerticalOffset="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
                android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
                android:paddingRight="14dp"
                android:popupBackground="@android:color/white"
                android:popupElevation="2dp"
                android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/spinner_sla" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvFeed"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/pbLoadMore"
                    android:scrollbars="none" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/pbLoadMore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llEmptyLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:src="@drawable/blush" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Your feed will appear here"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llAccessDeniedLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="To access, tell us your due date &amp; create\naccount"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llCreateAccount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_btn_feedback_pink"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <TextView
                style="@style/MTS_ExtraSmall_1.Light"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Create account"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabQA"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="116dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/material_layout_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/up_arrow_small"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/arrow_splash"
        app:fabSize="mini" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I remove NestedScrollView the app works. I don't know what I am doing wrong? Here is what I get on log.:

```
16:00:07.070 14426-14437/in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app I/art: Backgroundsticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 133954(7MB) AllocSpace objects,3(48KB) LOS objects, 7% free, 93MB/101MB, paused 2.393ms total158.307ms
03-27 16:00:09.233 14426-14433/in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app W/art:Suspending all threads took: 97.543ms
03-27 16:00:09.266 14426-14437/in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app W/art:Suspending all threads took: 32.883ms
03-27 16:00:09.338 14426-14437/in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app I/art:Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 206445(16MB)AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 15% free, 84MB/100MB, paused35.005ms total 284.141ms
03-27 16:00:20.769 14426-14432/in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app I/art:Thread[3,tid=14432,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xa4562700,peer=0x12c050d0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
03-27 16:00:20.969 14426-14432/in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.app I/art: Wrotestack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: post the logcat stacktrace during crash...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Didn't get any error but still I posted the logcat.

Comment: Use strict mode in activity to identify why and where your main thread is getting blocked.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seems to be related to a missing dependency. Do you have `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'` as an example or additional dependencies configured (such as "in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.CustomSpinner" is not available) ?

## Update

Important point I noticed in your logs, I see lots of memory consumption. It can be that the application is stuck doing some background logic as well. My advice try running you app without "in.mylo.pregnancy.baby.CustomSpinner" to see if its causing this issue to happen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have lready added that dependency. If I haven't I wouldn't be able to use recyclerView

Comment: It's working properly at my end, can you please share your "com.android.support" dependencies?

Comment: I'm using version 25.0.2

Comment: Can you review my update about a logic running in the background causing the application to get stuck?